# VB.NET VbNewLine

Tags: vb.net, string, textbox, line

I have a multilined textbox and this code:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.text + vbNewLine + mystring
End if
```

The problem is when I hit enter it jumps to the next line instead of going to the new line and position the cursor at the last character.I was thinking about making it somehow press the Back button so it gets back to the line above,but that's not possible.

Comment: Try using the [TextBox.SelectionStart Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It wouldn't work,I tried.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add the string `mystring` to the textbox on a new line and leave the cursor where it was?

Comment: I feel like you almost have a question here, but it's still a little unclear what you're asking. I don't want to vote to close just yet. Please give some more details about the desired behavior.

Comment: no,the previous text entered remains the same and then it pastes mystring into the new line,but the cursor is being positioned even 1 line below, on a new line.I want to make that cursor be right after mystring,on the same line of course

Comment: FYI Use & instead of + in VB.Net to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in the `KeyDown` event, all you have to do is tell it to *not* proceed with the actual key press. Because as it stands you're currently adding a new line but so is also the system (since you pressed the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key).

To intercept the actual key press and keeping it from getting passed onto the `TextBox`, all you have to do is to set the [**`SuppressKeyPress` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress(v=vs.110).aspx) to `True`:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    TextBox1.AppendText(vbNewLine & mystring)
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
End If
```

As noted in the comments concatenation should be done with the ampersand (`&`) operator, and `TextBox1.AppendText(...)` is better to use since it will make the code easier to read.

Comment: I would suggest using `TextBox1.AppendText(...)` instead of that concatenation.  Less fireworks.

Comment: @LarsTech : Ah, you're right. And I should also have used the ampersand to concatenate as I always do otherwise. -- Fixed. For some reason I didn't think of changing the original code at first, even though it bothers me when someone concatenates strings with the plus operator.

Comment: @AndrewHenz : No problem. Glad I could help!